# Intimation from PSQL trigger

Tags: c, perl, postgresql, triggers

In my program, I am accessing Postgresql database.

I don't want to watch database regularly,

So When ever the specified table get changed by various actions ( insert, update, delete ),
I need to get some signal or message to my program,

So I have an idea to use Triggers, But I don't know how to send signal or API or message to my program ( it can be C or perl program ) from Trigger,

If I get the signal I will read from database and I will get the updates, 
If I get API I will parse API and get update

How can I do this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PostgreSQL's [`NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-notify.html) statement in the trigger and have the interested session invoke the [`LISTEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-listen.html) statement. `LISTEN` doesn't block. It simply registers interest in a named condition. Messages will be delivered asynchronously to that session when the trigger calls `NOTIFY` with the same condition name.

In Perl, you probably won't use the `LISTEN` statement directly. DBD::Pg, for instance, provides a specific mechanism, [pg_notifies](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#pg_notifies), to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Using this whether I can send signal to my perl or c program.

Comment: @sganesh: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to say, or even whether it's a question or a statement.

Comment: I don't want to use this because it need loops and if I put sleep(30) in between time if I inserted any row I can't get intimation immediately, after 30 sec only I can get,

So I need better way,

Comment: The `LISTEN` mechanism fires immediately. Perhaps the Perl API I referenced requires polling, but there may be other mechanisms that use `LISTEN` more effectively.